Why does Azure Trusted Signing fail with 200 OK and RequestFailedException when signing a digest from code?
Related question: 79166535.
I have set up Azure Trusted Signing:

My organisation is validated
A certificate profile is created
"Trusted Signing Certificate Profile Signer" role is added

Then, when running the following code in C#, using the Azure.CodeSigning.Sdk:
await using var stream = File.OpenRead("...");
var digest = await SHA512.HashDataAsync(stream);

var endpoint = new Uri("https://weu.codesigning.azure.net/");
const string codeSigningAccountName = "...";
const string certificateProfileName = "...";

var client = new CertificateProfileClient(new InteractiveBrowserCredential(), endpoint);

var signRequest = new SignRequest(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, digest);
var signOperation = await client.StartSignAsync(codeSigningAccountName, certificateProfileName, signRequest);
var response = await signOperation.WaitForCompletionAsync();

It fails with a RequestFailedException without details, wrapped in a 200 OK http result:
The response fails with:
Service request failed.
Status: 200 (OK)
Content:
{"operationId":"d83663c9-03ee-475e-b585-87de006601a0","status":"Failed","signature":null,"signingCertificate":null,"counterSignature":null}

I have clearly misunderstood something here, but can't figure out what because the error message is empty.

Are you getting the error locally ?

@Harshitha, I run the code locally, yes.

I have later found that signing with SignatureAlgorithm.RS512 works, while SignatureAlgorithm.ES512 as in my example does not.

Is your issue resolved ?

Sort of. I can sign a hash/digest, but still do not know why signing with ES512 fail this way. Another issue not related to this question is what to do with the response. I have yet to find any resources which help with that. All paths lead to signtool.exe, which is frustrating.

As you correctly identified, this error occurs because the digest algorithm does not match the signature algorithm.
var digest = await SHA512.HashDataAsync(stream);
var signRequest = new SignRequest(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, digest);
I believe Status: 200 (OK) means that the request was successfully received, and processed by the server.

Where can I find information about matching digest and signature algorithms?
